# Inputting from msvcrt.getch() not working as intended

Tags: python, user-input, msvcrt

I want to use the msvcrt.getch function as in the following example:

```
print 'Press s or n to continue:\n'
input_char = msvcrt.getch()
if input_char.upper() == 'S': 
   print 'YES'
```

But when I use it like this:

```
n = msvcrt.getch()
print(n)
```

The output is

```
b'\xff'
```

and it doesn't ask user for input.

Is this what is expected from msvcrt.getch() method?
If not, how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue as well!

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825306/msvcrt-getch-returning-ba-instead-of-a)

msvcrt returns a byte string and will require decoding using the below:

```
input_char = bytes.decode(msvcrt.getch(), encoding="utf-8")
```

or you can change the code to compare :b[input_char]